# React JS: How to call a function to return JSX code?

Tags: render

I'm new to react and I'm trying to create a JSX element in a function. The JSX should dynamically add 2 buttons each time when you click the button. However, when render() calls this function, it isn't rendering the element (white page in browser).

How would I go about fixing this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

````
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        fields: [{key:'key', val:'val'}]
    }
    this.renderPanel = this.renderPanel.bind(this);
  }

  addField() {
    this.setState({
      fields: [...this.state.fields, {key:'key', val:'val'}],
    })
  }

  renderPanel(){
      return <div>
      <form>
          <div id="testingAPanel">
              {()=>this.state.fields.map((input,index) => {return(
                  <tr>
                  <input type='button' id={index} value={input.key} />
                  <input type='button' id={index} value={input.val} />
                  <br/>
                  </tr>
                  )}
              )}

          </div>
      </form>
      <button onClick={ () => this.addField() }>
          CLICK ME TO ADD AN INPUT
      </button>
  </div>
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div class = 'test'>
            {()=>this.renderPanel()}
        </div>      
    );
  }
}

export default Test;```
````

Answer (score 0):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  buttonClick(){
    console.log("came here")
    
  }
  
  subComponent() {
    return (<div>Hello World</div>);
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="patient-container">
          <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
          {this.subComponent()}
       </div>
     )
  }
  


}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

it depends on your need, u can use either  `this.renderIcon()` or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) `this.renderIcon.bind(this)`

**UPDATE**

This is how you call a method outside the render.

```
buttonClick(){
    console.log("came here")
}

render() {
   return (
       <div className="patient-container">
          <button onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
       </div>
   );
}
```

The recommended way is to write a separate component and import it.

Comment: So this helped me partially. Now I can see the main button. However, when I click it doesn't add the new fields. However, if I put all renderPanel() code in render(), it works fine.